# code management of ERP Customization using Subversion (SVN)

Tags: svn, repository, customization, erp

I did start to create a repository for managing our EBS customizations.
Though I am not so sure if my current design is good, as I have some problems.

For example, I did start the SVN repository structure based on Unix tree.
1 folder for every module, and then divided in some folders like bin, admin, sql...

XXXPO_TOP
- admin
- bin
- data
- doc
- forms
- media
- reports
- sql
XXXQA_TOP
...

Though, how to create some new customisations that are accross different modules?
Should we create a branch for any customization with the entire set of modules from the trunc and just using tags? In that way, it may be not easy to quickly find your changes.

How to store all java files, for example that are coming from some Framework modules, I think about iStore, and where you don't have the "ususal" structure of files?

Do some of you have already implemented some good and solid repositories in order to proper develop your customizations?